# previuos year value should add to current year values and give summation

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to insert to new row with this year summation +previous year value insert to new rawwiend of this year

example

> in 2014-01-01 sum off all values of rainfall = 2245 for 2013 and sum for 2012 = 2250 when 2014-01-01 should insert new raw to table 2013 values is 2245+2250

how can i do it........ please help me i can get sum of 2013 from this code but how can i add to previous year value  and insert with sum to table year as 2013

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `clima_data`.`mas_aver_curve` ( `year` , `cumulative`  ) 
SELECT year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'))as year round(sum(rainfall),1) 
FROM reg_data3 G
GROUP BY  year(date) ;
```

Comment: I am guessing - `mas_aver_curve` table already has entries for year=2013 and 2012 but not for 2014. If this is the case then you need to update the table for 2012 and 2013. For 2014 you should `insert`

Comment: @HussainTamboli totally mis undersanding dear but thanks

Comment: provide some sample data maybe, since year 2014 hasn't happened yet maybe there's no data for 2014 in `reg_data3` unless you want year '2014' to contain the cumulative value of 2245+2250?

Comment: @TinTran there is values in cumulative table example for 2012 = '17000' and we get summation from reg_data3 for rainfall sum of rainfall 2013 = 2250 we shold add to that value to 2013 cumulative value = 170000+2250 (this should add to end of 2013 but i don't want that) but atlest first thing how can  i do it please help me

Comment: here play with this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a54c/5/0), I have set up some test data based on what you provided and let us know what you want to see as the end result before you try to insert it into `mas_aver_curve`

Comment: this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a54c/10/1) has the bottom query as running total for each year, if that's what you want or not

Comment: so did that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
INSERT INTO mas_aver_curve (year, cumulative)
SELECT '2014-01-01', ROUND(SUM(rainfall), 1) rainfall
  FROM reg_data3 G
 WHERE date >= '2012-01-01'
   AND date <  '2014-01-01';
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23a76/1)** demo

Comment: this is correct when all data infrom reg_data3, thanks dear for you kind request

Comment: ah! so that's what you wanted, just one new row for 2014

Answer (score 0):

to get sum from all previous year into the cumulative field use this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db303/1)

```
INSERT INTO mas_aver_curve(year,cumulative)
SELECT year(date) as year,
      (SELECT sum(rainfall)
       FROM reg_data3 as G
       WHERE G.date <= G2.date) as cumulative
FROM reg_data3 G2
GROUP BY year;
```

if you wanted a row of 2014 along with all your other years to have a running total, use this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55767/1/0)

```
INSERT INTO mas_aver_curve(year,cumulative)
SELECT year(date) as year,
       (SELECT sum(rainfall)
        FROM reg_data3 as G
        WHERE G.date <= G2.date) as cumulative
FROM (SELECT date,rainfall FROM reg_data3 G2
      UNION
      SELECT curdate() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR,0
     )G2
GROUP BY year;
```